# Compile error of Method gettext() is undefined for the type object and require Cast

Tags: java, selenium

I am new to Java and trying my hands on selenium. I took some online course as well. While coding stuck here for a compilation error. please help. As this is not solved unable to move forward.

```
Demo.java

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\E\\Java\\Software\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(); 
        FacebookLogin FB = new FacebookLogin();
        String String = FB.FacebookLoginDetails();
        System.out.println(String);     
    }
}

Facebooklogin.java
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;

import org.openqa.selenium.By.ByCssSelector;

public class FacebookLogin 

{

    public String FacebookLoginDetails() {      
    WebDriver driver1 = new ChromeDriver();
    driver1.get("https://login.salesforce.com/?locale=in");
    driver1.findElement(By.cssSelector("#username")).sendKeys("nitin010583@gmail.com");;
    driver1.findElement(By.name("pw")).sendKeys("narendra");
    driver1.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='Login']")).click();
    System.out.println(driver1.findElement(((Object) By.cssSelector("div#error.loginError")).gettext()));   
    return ("Success");

    }
}
```

I'm seeing an error when trying to read error text. I googled but did not understand how to solve the problem.

Comment: Try reading the javadocs and you will see that the method name is `getText` not `gettext`  https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getText--

Answer (score 2):

You're casting `org.openqa.selenium.By.ByCssSelector` to `java.lang.Object` which doesn't have method `gettext()`.

You need to replace:

```
System.out.println(driver1.findElement(((Object)By.cssSelector("div#error.loginError")).gettext()));
```

line with:

```
System.out.println(driver1.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#error.loginError")).getText());
```

Comment: Good spotting, did not notice the cast